# Переписать код в более компактный [Py3]

Tags: python-3.x, ооп

```
import random
from getpass import getpass

suits = [
'Spades',
'Dimonds',
'Clubs',
'Hearts']

cards = [
'Two',
'Three',
'Four',
'Five',
'Six',
'Seven',
'Eight',
'Nine',
'Ten',
'Jack',
'Queen',
'King',
'Ace']

deck = {}
for suit in suits:
    for card, cost in zip(cards, [*range(2,11), 10, 10, 10, 11]):
        deck['{} of {}'.format(card, suit)] = cost

deck_keys = list(deck.keys())
random.shuffle(deck_keys)

d_card_1_key = deck_keys.pop(2)
d_card_2_key = deck_keys.pop(3)
d_card_1 = deck.pop(d_card_1_key)
d_crad_2 = deck.pop(d_card_2_key)
d_score = d_card_1 + d_crad_2
dealer_start = d_card_1_key + ' and ' + d_card_2_key

card_1_key = deck_keys.pop(0)
card_2_key  = deck_keys.pop(1)
card_1 = deck.pop(card_1_key)
card_2 = deck.pop(card_2_key)
score = card_1 + card_2
player_start = card_1_key + ' and ' + card_2_key

print('\nYour score is', score)
print('Your cards are:', player_start)

print('\nDealer score is:', d_score)
print('Dealer cards are:', dealer_start)


def Game(deck, deck_keys, score, player_start, d_score, dealer_start):
    if score == 22:
        score -= 1
        print('\nYou got BlackJack !')
        pass
    if d_score == 22:
        score -= 1
        print('\nDealer got BlackJack !')
        pass
    while 1:
        choiсe = getpass('\nTake the card ?')
        if choiсe == 'y':
            taken_card_key = deck_keys.pop()
            taken_card = deck.pop(taken_card_key)
            score += taken_card
            print('\nThe card is:', taken_card_key)
            print('Now your score is:', score)
        else:
            while d_score <= 15:
                d_taken_card_key = deck_keys.pop()
                d_taken_card = deck.pop(d_taken_card_key)
                d_score += d_taken_card
                print('\nLast Dealer card was:', d_taken_card_key)
            result(score, d_score)
            break
    return score


def result(score, d_score):
    print('\nDealer final score is:', d_score)
    print('Your final score is:', score)
    if score == 21:
        print('\nYou got 21 Congratulations !')
    if d_score == 21:
        print('\nDealer got 21 !')
    if score < d_score and score <= 21 and d_score <= 21:
        print('\nYou lose !')
    if score > d_score and score <= 21 and d_score <= 21:
        print('\nYou win !')
    if score < d_score and score > 21 and d_score > 21:
        print('\nYou win !')
    if score > d_score and score > 21 and d_score > 21:
        print('\nYou lose !')
    if score > d_score and score > 21 and d_score <= 21:
        print('\nYou lose !')
    if score < d_score and score < 21 and d_score > 21:
        print('\nYou lose !')
    if score == d_score:
        print('\nDraw !')


Game(deck, deck_keys, score, player_start, d_score, dealer_start)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Для начала `getpass()` заменить на `input()`.
2. Заменить "Take the card?" на "Take a card?", а "choise" на "choice".
3. Засунуть инициализацию колоды и первоначальную раздачу карт в Game().
4. Game() обернуть в цикл while, чтобы можно было без проблем играть несколько раз.
5. Сократить эти два условия до одного:

   `if score > d_score and score > 21 and d_score > 21:
       print('\nYou lose !')
   if score > d_score and score > 21 and d_score <= 21:
       print('\nYou lose !')`

->

```
if score > d_score and score > 21:
       print('\nYou lose !')
```

И вообще сократить нагромождение if-ов примерно так:

```
def result(score, d_score):
    print('Your final score is:', score)
    print('\nDealer final score is:', d_score)
    if score == 21:
        print('\nYou got 21 Congratulations !')
    if d_score == 21:
        print('\nDealer got 21 !')
    if score > d_score:
        if score <= 21 and d_score <= 21:
            print('\nYou win !')
        else:
            print('\nYou lose !')
    elif score < d_score:
        if score <= 21 and d_score <= 21:
            print('\nYou lose !')
        elif score > 21 and d_score > 21:
             print('\nYou win !')
        else:
             print('\nYou lose !')
    else:
        print('\nDraw !')
```

*(поменял местами первые два принта, чтобы был такой же порядок вывода, как при расдаче)*

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил choiSe и два этих if'a.
А вот getpass нужен для скрытия ввода при выборе, его можно оставить.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй suits и cards засунуть в другой файл .py (например - `constants.py`).

После, импортни его в основной файл (`import constants`)
и теперь вместо `suits` используй `constants.suits` и т.д. .

Comment: В чем заключается компактность?

Comment: Код не будет нагроможден переменными.

Comment: Каким образом использование ``constants.suits`` вместо ``suits`` уменьшает "нагромождение" переменных?